# In my Apache2 access.log, how do I filter what gets displayed?

Tags: linux, apache, unix, logging

Someone told me to do this in order to keep track of latest people hitting my server:

```
tail -f access.log
```

However, this shows all the "includes", including the JS file, the graphics, etc. What if I just want to see the pages that people hit? How do I filter that using tail -f?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pipe the output through `grep` or `awk`. For example, if all your pages have `.php` in the URL, you can try the following:

```
tail -f access.log | grep '\.php'
```

If your access logs include a referrer field, the above will also match many resources. We're only interested in events with `.php` in the request field, not the referrer field. By using `awk`, we can distinguish between these.

```
tail -f access.log | awk '$7 ~ /\.php/ { print }'
```

You may need to adjust `$7` if your log format is unusual.

Answer (score 0):

if you're serving .php files:

```
tail -f access_log | grep ".php"
```

alternatively, if all your includes are in a folder named "include", for example:

```
tail -f access_log | grep "include" -v
```

or if you want to count hits to a certain file:

```
grep "filename" access_log -c
```